# parsing email in java returns no entry

Tags: java

currently I'm creating an email service for my hobby project for newly signed up users. This is the relevant part of the code, which causes me some headache:

```
private Message createEmail(String firstName, String password, String email) throws MessagingException {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(getEmailSession());
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM_EMAIL));
    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email, false)[0]);
    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(CC_EMAIL, false)[0]);
    message.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT);
    message.setText("Hello " + firstName + ", \n \n Your new account password is: " + password + "\n \n " +
            "The support team");
    message.setSentDate(new Date());
    message.saveChanges();

    return message;
}
```

I have two problems with this line `message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email, false)[0]);` (and of course the same problem with the next line below it):

1. On the internet, if I google after it, everywhere it is used like this:

`message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(email, false);`

so, without the indexing. But if I remove the indexing, I get an IDE error, which says, that the function requires a type of `Address`, but it has got `InternetAddress[]`, an array. That's why I put the indexing.

2. But if I leave the indexing and run the app and register a new user, I get the error in the console: `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`. Obviously, the `InternetAddress[]` array is empty. But why?

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: You could try to debug and see what `InternetAddress.parse(email, false)` is returning. Also what value has your `email` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html), it should be [`new InternetAddress(String, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress(java.lang.String,%20boolean)), which

> Parse[s] the given string and create[s] an InternetAddress.

instead of [`InternetAddress.parse(String, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20boolean)), which

> Parse[s] the given sequence of addresses into InternetAddress objects.

Comment: Indeed, that's it. Thanks.